# Error initializing submodule on github

Tags: git, github

I get the following error when trying to sync my local repo using the github client.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hyjq4.png

I've tried the following to no avail:

1. changing permissions to 775 on local repo folder per error message indicating its some writable issue
2. Deleting the local repo and recloning the external github repo again

Any ideas as to what this means and how to fix it?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. The error occurs when I first clone the repo and again when I try to sync a commit. Google's no help.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a folder above the current directory that is already a git repository.  You might want to try cloning your project into a different directory first, making your changes and then checking them in.

If you need to have it nested under a parent git repository then you need to lookup how to manage submodules.

http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules

Answer (score 0):

Had this problem, but nested git repositories was not the issue.

Try using command line / terminal. Sometimes the client gets stuck. (e.g. git status, git add "file", git commit -m "message", git push origin master).

Also could try quitting and reopening the Github client and making sure it's up to date.